# Insertion of record by iteration create records in irregular order

Tags: java, ms-access, odbc

When i do insert in java that is connected to a `MS Access` through `ODBC` connection the order that i send the record is missing.

```
For(i=0; i<1000; i++)
  {
       insert(value);
  }
```

The First record in `MS Access` should be `id = 1` right. But it starts with `id = 20` something like irregular order. Can anyone tell me why this is happening when the record is more than 200 otherwise the order is maintained correctly in `MS Access`.

Comment: Sound like your id is an autonumber. If you insert and delete 20 records, the next inserted will start with the next number.

Comment: id is auto_generated one but the record itself in irregular order. @Gustav

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamental behaviour of a database table.

It is not a spreadsheet, and there is no "order" except one that you specify, and that is not at the table level but when you query the data.